# Let $f$ be differentiable for all $x$, $f(0)=0$, & $\exists a,b>0$ such that $a\le f'(x)\le b$ all $x\ge0$. Prove $ax\le f(x)\le bx$ for $x\ge0$

Tags: real-analysis

Looking for hints on this, I have worked out that we know $f'(x)>0$ so $f$ is strictly increasing for all $x\ge0$ and I assume we need to use somewhere $f(0)=0$ but I do not know how to begin

My application of mean value theorem:

Apply mean value theorem for $f$ on the interval from $[0,x]$

There exists a $c\in (0,x)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)}{x}$

Hence,

$a\le f'(x)\le b\rightarrow a\le \frac{f(x)}{x}\le b$ for $c,x>0$ and it follows $ax\le f(x)\le bx$ for $c,x>0$

Lastly, in the case $x=c=0$ it is trivial.

■

Comment: Mean value theorem or fundamental theorem of calculus will do it

Comment: Suppose not. Then use the mean value theorem

Comment: I would use the monotonicity of integration.

Comment: @user25959 MVT yes. FTC no! The FTC has hypotheses that are not satisfied here...

Comment: @JoshB. Nope. Given just that $f$ is differentiable it does not follow that $f$ is the integral of $f'$, so properties of integration are nnot going to help.

Comment: Oh wow... that is weird. Thanks for pointing that error out.

In case anyone wants to know which hypothesis is missing: $f'(x)$ is not stated to be continuous so we can't use FTC.